# SQLite в Xcode и поддержка русского языка

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, sqlite3

Добрый вечер!
При запросе к БД получаю:

```
SELECT zid FROM favorites WHERE name = "–ê–ª–µ–∫—Å–µ–π –®–∏–ø–µ–ª–∫–∏–Ω"
```

Строка запроса перед этим:

```
const char *query_statement = [querySQL UTF8String];
```

Как подружиться с русскими буквами в Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался.

Это глюк лога - в нём вместо русских букв отображается абракадабра :)

На самом деле, при записи и чтении БД, русские буквы отображаются корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String...
```

Тут можете посмотреть подробнее https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608251

Так же для SQLite Unicode есть статья на хабре http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/136135/